# Piping Replace to New File

Tags: powershell

```
$x = Get-Content($file)
if ($x -match("~")) {
  $x -replace("~","~`n") | Out-File $file
}
```

This is the snippet of code I am using. I have debugged up until this point and the code isn't updating after I replace the character tilda `~` with itself and then create a new line. When I output it to the command window and comment out the `| Out-File $file` the code works fine. When I try to pipe the new result back into the original file the code doesn't "unwrap" the file.

Comment: By the way $file is the path to the file location such as: C:/dir1/dir2/foo.txt

Comment: Can you post a sample of the text file?

Comment: Sure Conan, it would be like: Line1*Item1*Item2~Line2*Item3*Item4~Line3*Item5*Item6~

Comment: The script should create a new line every time "~" occurs and overwrite the old file with the "unwrapped" version. It might be because the references aren't passing...

Answer (score 2):

The replacement works just fine. However, you're inserting just linefeed characters (LF, `` `n ``), not the combination of carriage-return and linefeed (CR-LF, `` `r`n ``) that Windows uses for encoding line breaks. Because of that you don't see line breaks when opening the file in Notepad. PowerShell accepts both LF and CR-LF as line break encoding, so you see correctly wrapped lines when you output the file there.

Change your code to this and you'll get the expected result:

```
(Get-Content $file) -replace '~', "~`r`n" | Set-Content $file
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I was actually checking the result in Command Window using echo. Stupid fix on my end. Thanks for your answer though! Upvoted for usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I was calling reader method above.

```
ForEach ($file in $Path){
    $Array = @()
    $reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($file)
```

I needed an array to determine if the file needed to be unwrapped to begin with. If the contents took up 1 line it needed to be unwrapped. If not then it did not. I essentially used streamreader which is going to store each line as an element in an array. I forgot to close $reader before so we had a producer-consumer issue and thus Out-File could not override $file.

Fixed Snippet:

```
if($Array.length -eq 1){
        $x = Get-Content($file)

        if($x -match("~")){
            $reader.close()
            ($x -replace("~","~`n")) | Out-File $file
            }

        }
```